# Push value of key-value pair of hash into array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, switch-statement

I have an array which assign values from a csv file which consists of 3 columns

CSV file:

```
Name,Age,City
Joe,30,NYC
Mary,32,Washington
.
.
.
n number of lines
```

so i pass this to my perl script and assign these variables

```
($name,$age,$city) = split(",",$_,3);
push @array, "$name,$age,$city";
```

However I have a key value pair in 2 hashes, which I want to push into this array.

this is the hash

```
%hash  = ('NYC' => NYC, 'Washington' => Virginia, and so on)
%hash2 = ('NYC' => US, 'Washington' => US, 'London' => UK, and so on)
```

I want to add 2 more columns, State and Country to my array, such that it ends up looking like

```
Name,Age,City,State,Country
Joe,30,NYC,NY,US
Mary,32,Washington,Virginia,US
.
.
.
n number of lines
```

I tried with switch statement

```
 switch($city){
            case "NYC"         {$state = "NY"; $country = "US";
                       push @array, "$name,$age,$city,$state,$country";
                               }
               }
```

But it didnt work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't work? What's the point of the hashes, you don't seem to be using them?

Comment: You should (1) use strict and warnings, as you are currently using a bunch of global variables which will make your code complex and confusing, and you have unquoted strings. (2) avoid switch/case as it is experimental and due to its use of smartmatch will do confusing things depending on the cases, just use an if/elsif statement or [Switch::Plain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch::Plain) if you really want switch/case syntax.

Comment: @zdim - You noticed right. I thought you just select the answer you deem as right and that would assign the vote. It seems I need to vote as well. Just did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, what you put on the array is a single string with all that's inside double quotes. This may well be what you meant to do but I'd like to go through this a step at a time.

The `push` takes a list so you can just list all variables to add, in which case no quoting is needed at all. To add "State" and "Country" just pull values out of your hashes for the key `$city`

```
push @array, $name, $age, $city, $hash{$city}, $hash2{$city};
```

But if this array is meant to acquire further records, how does one distinguish them?  One way is to add an array reference each time, so

```
push @array, [ $name, $age, $city, $hash{$city}, $hash2{$city} ];
```

where braces `[ ]` build an anonymous array and return a a reference to it, which itself can be an array element since it is a scalar.  Retrieval of individual items isn't great since you must index into this, like `$array[$index]->[0]` for name (or shorthand `$array[$index][0]`). But if you most often need all of them then it's perfect: `my @data = @{ $array[$index] };`

Another way would be to add a hash reference instead, using `{ }`, for example such as

```
push @array, { name => $name, age => $age, city => $city, 
      state => $hash{$city}, country => $hash2{$city} };
```

where you can then retrieve values as `$array[$index]->{name}` (etc). This is clearly well suited for working with individual components.

Another way is to indeed add a string for each record; then add hash values under quotes

```
push @array, "$name,$age,$city,$hash{$city},$hash2{$city}";
```

since hash values can be evaluated inside a double-quoted string.

At any rate, there is no need to switch on `$city` -- that's precisely what a hash is for, to associate a value with a key so that the value can then be directly retrieved for the key.

---

I'd like to add, how about naming those hashes in a more informative manner?

For example

```
my %state   = (NYC => 'NY', Washington => 'Virginia');            # ...
my %country = (NYC => 'US', Washington => 'US', London => 'UK');  # ...
```

and then you have the far clearer

```
push @records, "$name,$age,$city,$state{$city},$country{$city}";
```

I also changed the array name.

A side note on naming.   I've used a convention where a hash name is singular ("state", not "states") with a rationale that it refers to a single and named item, `$state{$city}` (state-for-city); with well chosen variable names it's obvious what this stands for. But this isn't a "rule" of any kind and plural is used just as as well ("states" instead of "state").

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Both of your suggestions worked. I didn’t know I could just use $hash{$city}. This solved my problem. I don’t know however if it possible to assign two values to one key. For eg %hash = ( NYC => “NY”,”NAM”, Washington => “Virginia”,”NAM”, London => “UK”,”EMEA”) and then be able to display the zones NAM,EMEA as another column.

Comment: @user3423407 Glad that it helped :).  A value for a key in the hash must be a _scalar_.  That means a single-valued thingy (or expression that works out to that), so it can't be a list. But  you can put there a reference since a reference _is_ a scalar.  For example `%h = (NYC => ['NY', 'NAM'], ...)` where `[ ... ]` is an arrayref, like what I used in the second line above.  Then you can extract values as: `@{$h{NYC}}` to get the list of both, or `$h{NYC}->[0]` for first (`NY`) and `->[1]` for the second.  Or you can use a hashref, like in the third line above.

Comment: @user3423407 That is a way to build complex data structures, see [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  Another principal way to use complex data is with classes, which of course offer far more than mere data organization.

Comment: @user3423407 Please let me know if what I dumped above in a comment is opaque or unclear!

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I have been playing around with this and it seems to work like a charm. Thanks a ton for taking the time to explain also introducing to perl data structures. I would love to learn more about parsing logs with perl, not sure if you can point me to some good documentation

Comment: @user3423407 Great, very glad to hear that it helps :).  Perl is great for that kind of work. It has superb string processing support, regex is fully integrated into the language, and there's a lot of very useful modules. There are docs but that may add up to more than you need. Perhaps select good a tutorial on the language, and use docs as reference?  [cont'd...]

Comment: @user3423407    The book "Learning Perl" used to be phenomenal, you work through it in a week and get useful working knowledge. I am not familiar with new editions, but my guess is that it may not be as readable but is far more complete. Should still be an excellent (jump-) starting point.  There is another very good book, "Modern Perl," by "chromatic" -- which is (also) legitimately available on internet: [Modern Perl 4e](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/). I've never read the thing but I did look here and there and it was all spot on, to the point, and well written.

Comment: @user3423407 And then there are all kinds of internet tutorials, but be careful. A good-looking resource is [learn.perl.org](https://learn.perl.org/).  All documentation is at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/); Note links on the left: see first _Overview_ and _Tutorials_.  I hope this helps, let me know if questions come up :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the guidance here. Your advice on using arrays and selecting specific index elements has made my script work like a charm.

Comment: I have been testing out this piece of code, and for the most part of it works fine. However I have noticed, that sometimes the value in the key value pair is mixed up. Am not able to figure out why

For eg
if key value is
%h = (NYC => "NY", London=>"UK"...)
the value when I pull the city $hash{$city}, it sometimes retrieves UK for NYC key. It is happening for different values, this is just an example. Please note my hash contains around 2000+ key-value pairs(all unique keys). .Any reason why

Comment: @user3423407  That'd be a direct error somewhere in code; you can be certain that a hash with `$h{NYC}` will always return `NY` ... if that's what was assigned to it (and wasn't overwritten with another value).  Perhaps when you ask for it the `$city` in fact contains `London`? Or the code (mistakenly) assigns `UK` to `$h{NYC}` at some point?  Print values at well-chosen points in the code, to see what's actually going on (debug).

Comment: @user3423407 It is often useful to bluntly dump the whole data structure for review. One tool that does this is the core [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).  There are yet others; I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) since its default is more concise (and its only purpose is to show data, while `Data::Dumper` really does quite a bit more), which you'd need to install.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems this Dumper module is not installed, I got a compilation error. However I tried debugging as follow

foreach (@array)
{
                        print "\n$_\n";
                ($name,$age,$city,$hash{$city}) = split(",",$_);
                        print "\n";
                        print "$name\n";
                        print "$age\n";
                        print "$city\n";
                        print "$hash{$city}\n"
                        print "\n";
}

It perfectly prints the correct value for the $hash{city} in $_

Comment: Continuing pervious comment


But when it starts printing for  print "$hash{$city} it seems to carry forward the previous value of the key.

For eg output is


Joe,30,NYC,NY        <==$_ output

Joe
30
NYC
NY


Mary,32,Washington,Virginia <==$_ output

Mary
32
Washington
NY                   <==somehow it continues to use the value of the previously mapped key.

Comment: @user3423407 I can't say much w/o seeing the code ... one guess: Do you use one hash, declared outside of that loop? If you were to have `my %h; foreach (...) { my %h ... }` then the `%h` inside the loop would "mask" ("shadow") the one outside, which could make it so that you see strange values when printing.  I can't guess what other things would make it appear that it doesn't update keys.  Could data itself be wrong? (Line for "Mary" could have "NY" or so)  I'm guessing here, w/o any code :)   Buy you can be sure that the hash variable in Perl can't misbehave like that.

Comment: @user3423407 Another way how bad data can mess it up: an incomplete/malformed data line can make your `split` in fact return other than expected (say, 3 fields instead of 4). So then code would assign to some variables but not to others, resulting in wrong assignments to hash elements.  Always check data!!  For starters, check whether all expected variables have indeed been assigned. Make certain you _always_ have `use warnings;` at the top of the script!  For one, that will warn when using undefined values, and of many bad hash operations. Otherwise ... it quietly falls back to its defaults.

Comment: how to post the code? the comments have a limited number of characters

Comment: @user3423407 If you believe that you have more than a simple-minded error and you've tried and you can't find it, that'd be for another question.  Comments are indeed bad for any code other than a short snippet, and morphing the question with follow-up work isn't a good idea. But don't haste (if you are indeed posting another question) -- make sure it's good, with all that it needs, and proof-read for typos etc.  A good question makes it far easier for people to give you good answers.

Comment: Thanks. I created 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732423/hash-key-value-not-being-retrieved-correctly

Comment: @user3423407 Yeah, saw that, thank you for the note.  That question needs improvement, I'll comment there...