# Hash key value not being retrieved correctly

Tags: perl, hash

```
*Editing to include the entire code

#Shell script

less file.txt | perl parseperl.pl > index.html

#This is the Perl file parseperl.pl
my @array;
while(<>)
{
($date,$name,$city) = split(",",$_,3);
%hash =(NY=>"NYC", Washington=>"Virginia", London=>"UK");
push @array, "$name, $city,$hash{$city}";
}
foreach(@array)
{
($date,$name,$city,$hash{$city}) = split(",",$_);
print "<tr>\n";
print "<td>$name</td>\n";
print "<td>$city</td>\n";
print "<td>$hash{$city}</td>\n";
}
```

The code for some reason takes the previous key's value in the output

For eg: this is the output

```
Joe NYC NY
Mary Washington NY
```

My input file is file.txt.

```
12/12 12:32:56,Joe,NYC
12/12 12:12:16,Mary,Washington
```

Please advise

---

*Edit*

My code works when I use this

```
($name, $city, $state) = split (/,/,$_)
```

Comment: The `while (<>)` reads all lines from all input files, but here you set a hard-coded `%hash` inside and don't use actual input.  I see that this is for a definite demo of the problem, but it won't work.  I suggest: put your actual code instead (trimmed down for a short example), which does read from files, and use it with a short sample file that you also show here.  (Another problem: `$state` isn't set from anywhere in this code snippet.)

Comment: @zdim - Posted it

Comment: @user3423407 Thank you -- now go back and nice and slow check what you posted: it won't print what you show.  This  is firstly because in the string `"$name, $city,$hash{$city}"` there is a space before `$city` so when you `split` it later on a comma you get ` $city` (with the leading space), which isn't a key in your hash.

Comment: Thanks @zdim . i made that change and ran and it still didnt print the correct map.

Please note it shows the correct value in $_, that is the key value shows
Joe,NYC,NY
Mary,Washington,Virginia

But when it finishes this line
($name,$city,$hash{$city}) = split(",",$_);
not sure why it is not retrieving the correct key value

Comment: 1. The space in the string, like @zdim mentioned. 2. I expect NY=>NYC should be NYC=>NY. 3. You don't chomp the hard return off of $_ so none of your lookup hash items will match. 4. You can't assign $hash{$city} from a split (which is why you're seeing previous values - try changing it to something else, like $state). 5.  Your hash assignment doesn't need to be inside the loop.

Comment: e.g. `($name, $city,$state) = split(",",$_);`

Comment: Can you then post the program that does what you say?  It's hard to see why, since the posted code won't do any of that.  Once you show the actual program we can fix it.

Comment: Just think about it, what is the value of `$city` when you assign `$hash{$city}`? Is it the value it had in the previous iteration of the loop, or the value that the previous `$city` item got assigned after the split. It's ambiguous and I don't expect anyone would be able to predict what value it will have. $city is being changed on the same line you're using it to do the lookup.

Comment: And I'd recommend reading up on hard returns ("\n"). The last value on each line is still a hard return, which is used in the $city key when you try to look up the "state", which will evaluate to undef.

Comment: The only reason you got $hash{$city} to return anything other than undef is because you assigned it in your second call to split, because it wasn't getting a defined value the first time you set it.

Comment: @zdim - that’s for editing and posting the final solution. Am still getting used to how use stack overflow. Again appreciate all the help you and others have provided here. Thanks a ton again!

Comment: @zdim - Yes it was a typo. I meant thanks. Do feel free to clean up whichever comments aren’t serving purpose here